# The specified cast from a materialized 'System.DateTime' type to the 'System.String' type is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 5 and when count() is called from below

```
string sqlStr = @"SELECT top 20 ID, 
               CAST(DOI as DATETIME) as IDate
               FROM DTable";

var results = db.Database.SqlQuery<SRVM>(sqlStr);


//get total count
var total = results.Count();
```

I get the error:

> The specified cast from a materialized 'System.DateTime' type to the
>   'System.String' type is not valid.

Any ideas why?

Comment: post the lines above it

Comment: You're missing relevant code parts.  We cannot infer what `results` type is.  Post its declaration as it is very relevant...

Comment: you have some column coming from db which is of DateTime type but here that property is string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are placing a DateTime into a String variable in a linq query.  I'm also guessing that the first to the query is the "results.Count()" which is actually executing the query and trying to populate whatever object you are populating.  If you change the Count() call to any method that will execute the call (ToList(), First(), ...) you will see the same error.

When you are projecting a DateTime into a string match sure you are calling ToString() with a format provider to make the conversion.

Answer (score 5):

When you use `Database.SqlQuery<T>` the exception targetsite is on : `T GetValue(System.Data.Common.DbDataReader, DateTime)`

review your entity class on this case T is **SRVM** you will find IDate field of type `string` which should be of type `Datetime`.

```
public string IDate { get; set; }
```

To

```
public Datetime IDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the addition to the above answers and fixes had to add is null check.

```
ISNULL(CREATEDDATETIME,'') AS WebOrderDate
```